# doing ampersand for multiple fields does not work in ruby

Tags: ruby

In ruby, I can do

```
['Hi', 'Yo'].map(&:upcase)
```

But what if I want to get both `:upcase` and `:downcase` at the same time?

Neither

```
['Hi', 'Yo'].map(&[:upcase,:downcase])
```

nor

```
['Hi', 'Yo'].map([&:upcase,&:downcase])
```

worked. :(

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: @Stefan I am expecting `[['HI', 'YO'], ['hi', 'yo']]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symbol#to_proc is useful as shorthand for the basic case of calling one method. If you want something more complicated just move to the longhand

```
['Hi', 'Yo'].map { |word| [word.upcase, word.downcase] }
```

which would return `[['HI', 'hi'], ['YO', 'yo']]` - which you could then call `flatten` on if what you want is `['HI', 'hi', 'YO', 'yo']` instead.

UPDATE: Since you actually want `[['HI','YO'], ['hi', 'yo']]` you can call transpose on the results

```
['Hi', 'Yo'].map { |w| [w.upcase, w.downcase] }.transpose
```

Note: The following is a terrible idea and no one should implement it in real code because the meaning of Array#to_proc would be completely non-obvious (does it call all and return an array, does it chain, does it pass parameters to a method, etc), but since you've asked for it you can do something like

```
class Array
   def to_proc
     lambda { |o| map { |m| o.send(m) } }
   end
end
```

which would allow

```
['Hi', 'Yo'].map(&[:upcase, :downcase]).transpose
```

to produce the answer you're asking for.  It does save a couple of characters but it's not worth the ambiguity it adds to the code.

Comment: I actually want to have `[['HI', 'YO'], ['hi', 'yo']]`

Comment: @QiangLi Updated based on what you actually want.

Comment: can you do it with & syntax/syntactic sugar?

Comment: @QiangLi Not without adding new methods to standard library classes which isn't worth the risk -- The & syntactic sugar is designed for the simple usual case, you wan't to do something beyond that.

Comment: yes, am asking ways to add new methods to the standard library classes. :)

Comment: @QiangLi Added, but it's a terrible idea to actually use it in real code due to ambiguity.

Answer (score 4):

What you have here:

```
['Hi', 'Yo'].map(&:upcase)
```

Is actually a short version of:

```
['Hi', 'Yo'].map(&:upcase.to_proc)
```

Which is a variant of:

```
['Hi', 'Yo'].map(&->(s) { s.send(:upcase) })
```

Or in other words:

```
['Hi', 'Yo'].map { |s| s.upcase }
```

The `&:x` notation is actually a special-case short-hand for situations like this and only works on a singular symbol. What you could do is define a `to_proc` method roughly like this:

```
class Array
  def to_proc
    ->(i) { inject(i) { |v, m| v.send(m) } }
  end
end
```

Where that method has to return a `Proc` object, a "lambda", which is defined here using the Ruby `-> (...) { ... }` notation.

Then you can call it like this:

```
['Hi', 'Yo'].map(&[:upcase, :downcase, :to_sym].to_proc)
# => [:hi, :yo]
```

Comment: I want `['Hi', 'Yo'].map(&[:upcase,:downcase])` to produce a result like `[['HI', 'YO'], ['hi', 'yo']]`

Comment: It'd be helpful if in the future you try and be more specific in your questions as to the output you want, as I could've done that for you.

Answer (score 1):

`&:symbol` works by defining a method `Symbol#to_proc`.

Here's an example of `Symbol#to_proc` defined in raw Ruby:

http://maximomussini.com/posts/ruby-to_proc/

```
class Symbol
  def to_proc
    ->(obj, args = nil) { obj.send(self, *args) }
  end
end
```

The C version adds a cache so recreating the block every time around doesn't slow us down.

To get what you want, define `Array#to_proc` and have at it!

Comment: how to do what you said in this example?